# Video Output through ssh on Raspbian Minimal + OpenCV example?

Tags: opencv, raspbian-stretch

I installed the minimal version of Raspbian Strech on the RPi3. Tried to run the python samples of OpenCV and failed cuz it needed a video output. Is there a work-around?

Comment: yes, attach a keyboard and mouse and monitor to your RPi

Comment: You need to describe in more deails, what code are you refering to, GUI or what and so on. As it is now I will vote to close it.

Comment: Adding a Keyboard, and monitor are not an option cuz there's no GUI in the Minimal Raspbian Strech. @MatsK I have the Minimal Ver of Raspbian Sterech which means no GUI, I wanna know if theres any tool to redirect that video output that's being produced by the OpenCV script, over the network into my with GUI PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV is not capable of creating an video stream. Its only possible to render a video to file.

So to stream the video file you need another application like GStreamer, VLC to mention some or use the streaming features in Python.

If you wan't to run the OpenCV examples then you have to install a desktop famwork on the Raspberry Pi.